# how to change ionic 3 tab max-width?

Tags: css, ionic3

I m trying to change tab max-width for 1 tab only, I did it with CSS class, but doesn't work, is there any other way to do it.

```
.resized_tab .tab-nav{ 
        max-width: 20px!important;
  }  
<ion-tabs  class="tabs tabs-dark" selectedIndex="1"   > 

    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"  tabTitle=" {{ 'home' | translate }}" 
      tabIcon="nnsm3-nnsm3"  > 
  </ion-tab> 

    <ion-tab    tabTitle=""  class="resized_tab" tabIcon="nnsm3-menu"    
     (ionSelect)="presentNotifications($event)">
   </ion-tab>  
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: where's the .tab-nav class?, maybe try .resized_tab only. try to remove .tab-nav

Comment: @MycoClaro it is not about spacing, I had tried it in all cases, it seems ionic tabs have a special  ways to do class  , even in the official doc  nothing helpful

Comment: if the first comment won't work you will can try this one.. 

<ion-tab    tabTitle=""  class="resized_tab" tabIcon="nnsm3-menu" style="max-width: 20px !important" (ionSelect)="presentNotifications($event)"></ion-tab>

Comment: Thanks @MycoClaro but it Doesn't work also.